# Devise How to allow User account update even if not confirmed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am using Devise with confirmable and I am asking if there is any way to allow User account update (email, username, password) without being confirmed yet? Basically, Devise/Warden responds with "You have to confirm your email address before continuing.". I want the user to be able to change the email if it was wrong, and resend the confirmation email.
Thanks for your suggestions :)

EDIT: Of course the user should be logged in, so he can change its details.

Comment: you want to update these details by a user,Admin ?

Comment: then I am not sure whats the issue with that you can easily send email and change email address by update_attributes bethod

Comment: i want to a user to update its details, so he's logged as a user, not an admin.

Comment: so you want user can login without confirm their account ?

Comment: yes, in the way that I am using it for an API with  simple_authentication_token so when creating an account, the token will be given an so the user is logged but it's not confirmed. So I just want that he can change its details without being confirmed, but all the others actions should be rejected if the account is not confirmed

Comment: you can just use update_attributes(params[:user]) method that will not call active record callbacks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using by default

```
config.allow_unconfirmed_access_for = nil
```

and prevent all authenticated and needed confirmed user controller actions with

```
before_filter :ensure_confirmed
```

and

```
def ensure_confirmed
  unless current_user.confirmed?
    head :unauthorized and return false
  end
end
```